# Can we insert data in few columns of table in Azure databricks databases?

Tags: azure, insert, multiple-columns, azure-table-storage, databricks

We are unable to insert data into few columns of a table in Azure databricks databases.

Doing an insert in all columns of a table are working fine. Can someone please suggest how we can insert data into limited required columns of a table over Azure databricks.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe try specifying the column as nullable when creating the table?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how we can insert data into limited required columns of a table over Azure databricks.

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks – SQL References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/insert)

Comment: This is an example how you insert data to all columns. The question is (mine too) how can you skip e.g. 'age' column. I get error even if I try to list columns where I want to insert values. All columns nullable for me.